# Do i really need to use a setter/getter with javascript ES6 Class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm playing around with ES6 `Class` and i'm wondering what the point is of using the `get` or `set` method for properties on that class. They seem pointless b/c you can set any arbitrary property on the class anyways.

For example with this class

```
class Group {

  constructor() {}

  set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  print() {
    console.log('this._name = ', this._name);
    console.log('this.name = ', this.name);
  }
}
```

I get these results

```
var group = new Group();
group._name = 'foo';
console.log('_name = ', group._name); => _name = foo
console.log('name = ', group.name); => name = foo
group.print(); => this._name = foo
               => this.name = foo

var group2 = new Group();
group2.name = 'bar';
console.log('_name = ', group2._name); => _name = bar
console.log('name = ', group2.name); => name = bar
group2.print(); => this._name = bar
                => this.name = bar
```

With the results of this example, it seems that by using the new `set` and `get` method just adds unnecessary bloat to my class.

Comment: Those methods are useful when you want to manipulate/modify the values before getting and setting them, if you don't want to do this, you don't need them.

Comment: If your getter and setter just read/write to another property and do nothing else, then they are indeed unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using the property accessors allows you to run additional code, for instance, checking the values are valid:

```
set name(newName) {
  if (newName === '')
      throw new Error("Name cannot be empty");
  this._name = newName;
}
```

Or computing complex properties:

```
get fullname() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

Comment: I can see your `set` example, but in your `get` example couldn't you just do away with the `get` and just have `fullname()...`?

Comment: You could do, but then it's a method call rather than a property.  I work in .NET a lot - it's very useful to have properties rather than methods sometimes.

Comment: Oh gotcha b/c with the `get` you can just do `myGroup.fullname` rather than `myGroup.fullname()`.